# Eloquent forget function creates extra key and alters my data format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Eloquent Query

```
$data = User::where('id','<=',3)->get();
```

Returns this data

```
 [{"id":1,"name":"Bob"},{"id":2,"name":"Tim"},{"id":3,"name":"Ash"}]
```

Attempting to forget/unset an entry

```
   foreach($data as $index=>$d){
        if($d->id == 2){
            //unset($data[$index]);
            $data->forget($index);
        }
    }
```

Results in the data being formatted this way

```
 {"0":{"id":1,"name":"Bob"}},"2":{"id":3,"name":"Ash"}}
```

Is there any way to have the data this way instead?

```
 [{"id":1,"name":"Bob"},{"id":3,"name":"Ash"}]
```

Comment: `$data->toJson();` ?

Comment: @nice_dev the format of the data returned will still be incorrect

Comment: Can you create a minimum reproducible example in [`this online playground`](https://collection-playground.atymic.dev/)?

Comment: you can use this :
`$array=[];
        foreach($data as $index=>$d){
            if($d->id!=2){
                array_push($array,$d);
            }
        }`
result is in `$array`

Comment: @AmirKhaledian is this the only way? is there no better option then to just delete that entry whilst retaining the current data format

Comment: ther is another way. but its not better